# List as an environmental variable in Java

Tags: javascript, java, api, environment-variables

I am passing an env variable as below.

```
es_nodes = ["IP:port", "IP:port", "IP:port"]
```

But the java application is considering it as a string rather than a list. Below is the error.

> Configuration error: Configuration error[env var es_nodes: elastic.ads.transport.hosts has type STRING rather than LIST]

How can I solve this?

Comment: Use a CSV or other delimited string and split it out when parsing the value from the environment

Comment: javascript is not relevant to your question at all - it is unrelated